# Multiple TFileStreams, TStreamWriter writing to same file

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I start using a `TFileStream` and `TStreamWriter` to write simple text logfiles (instead of old `Writeln(T,....)`). And I have multiple applicatiosn writing to the same logfile.
Each appplication has its own `TFileStream` of course and they each open the file like this

```
FFileStream:=TFileStream.Create(LogName, fmOpenReadWrite+fmShareDenyNone)
FExporter:=TStreamWriter.Create(FFilestream, TEncoding.UTF8);
FExporter.NewLine:=#$0A;
FExporter.AutoFlush:=TRUE;
```

and write to the file with

```
  FExporter.BaseStream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
  FExporter.Write('['+DateToStr(Now, FDateTimeFormat)+'] ['+TimeToStr(Now, FDateTimeFormat)+'] [#'+Lead0(GetCurrentThreadId, 5)+']: '+EntryText);
  FExporter.WriteLine;
```

the result is somewhat "unsatisfactory" as the lines are displaced, empty lines in between and does not seem to work.

HOW would I do that correctly?

Comment: May I ask why you have several applications using the *same* log file? Anyway you'll need some kind of synchronization if you really want to do that.

Comment: You can use a named mutex/semaphore to synchronize writes to the same log file, especially across process boundaries.

Comment: modify your design, make a service that receives log entries via IPC and the service writes the log file

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Writing multiples lines at the same time in multiples process may result in unexpected continue, because parallels execution.

You should assure that you are writing a block continually so WriteLine shoud be send inside the write using lineBreak at the end.

So the way you can write should be:

```
  FExporter.BaseStream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
  FExporter.Write('['+DateToStr(Now, FDateTimeFormat)+'] ['+TimeToStr(Now, FDateTimeFormat)+'] [#'+Lead0(GetCurrentThreadId, 5)+']: '+EntryText + System.slineBreak);
  //FExporter.WriteLine;
```

**Update1:**
As the link Oliver posted, sometime it can not work if the message size to be written is bigger than the OS file sector and, at that very moment, other process also try to write a message. Thus in this case the result content might be mixed.

So doing what I first purpose you would increase the probability to have the desired result, but may not be the solution in 100% of the cases.

To be 100% sure of writing continuous log in a single file, using multiples process, you should create a log process to receive a message from the others and to be the only responsible for writing synchronized log throughout threads.

Comment: It doesn't work because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765419/is-writefile-atomic).

Comment: I also changed the autoflush to false and flush after the write. Works now :-)

Comment: @WolfgangBures: When you say that it "works now", did you try it only once? Does it work 100% of all times if you stress test it, or only 90%? 50%?

Comment: I have yet (almost two days later) not seen a single failure. Maybe just lucky :-)